# Dynamically composing a view with Aurelia

Tags: javascript, webpack, aurelia

I am trying to dynamically compose a view, but at run time i get the error `Error: Unable to find module with ID: app/components/customers/customer-type-view-converter.html.` I’m using webpack.

Here’s the view converter that i’m using

```
 import {PLATFORM} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class CustomerTypeViewConverter {
    toView(type: string) {
     return  type  == 'LEGAL' ? PLATFORM.moduleName("createLEGALcustomer.html") : PLATFORM.moduleName("createNATURALcustomer.html")
    }
  }
```

here's the template that calls the convertor

```
<template>

    <require from="./customer-type-view-converter"></require>
    <ux-dialog style="min-width:500px">

        <ux-dialog-header>
            <h1>Create Customer</h1>
        </ux-dialog-header>

        <ux-dialog-body>
            <form class="form-horizontal">

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="name" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Customer Type:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <select value.bind="customer.customerType">
                            <option value="NATURAL">Person</option>
                            <option value="LEGAL">Company or Organisation</option>
                        </select>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <compose view.bind="customer.customerType | customerTypeView"></compose>

            </form>

        </ux-dialog-body>

        <ux-dialog-footer>
            <button click.trigger="controller.cancel()">Cancel</button>
            <button click.trigger="submit()">Ok</button>
        </ux-dialog-footer>

    </ux-dialog>

</template>
```

Comment: Would you mind adding the code you have in `customer-type-view-converter.js`, please?

Comment: was already in there, but formatted it more appropriately to make it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues here. Firstly. the class name should have been CustomerTypeView**Value**Converter in order for Aurelia to reconise it as a special class that doen't require a view.

And in the Value converter itself the html files should have been prefixed with`./` so webpack could find them

updated value converter below

```
 import {PLATFORM } from 'aurelia-framework';

export class CustomerTypeViewValueConverter  {
    toView(type: string) {
     return  type  == 'LEGAL' ? PLATFORM.moduleName("./createLEGALcustomer.html") : PLATFORM.moduleName("./createNATURALcustomer.html")
    }
  }
```